# How to store and get Cart Items to localstorage with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage, reduce, redux-reducers

I'm using **Redux toolkit** and adding product items to the cart using redux in my eCommerce app, products are adding to the cart perfectly also I tried to store the added products to the `localstorage` which is also working fine but the thing is How can I use those items from `localstorage` to display the `<CartItems>` even after refreshing the page.

Here is my reducer:-

```
const productItemsSlice = createSlice({
    name: "product",
    initialState: {
        items: [],
        totalQuantity: 0,
        localStorageItems: [],
    },
    reducers: { 
        addProduct(state, action) {
            const newItem = action.payload;

            const existingItem = state.items.find((item) => item.id === newItem.id);

            state.totalQuantity++;

            if (!existingItem) {
                state.items.push({
                    id: newItem.id,
                    price: newItem.price,
                    quantity: 1,
                    totalPrice: newItem.price,
                    name: newItem.name,
                    image: newItem.image,
                    category: newItem.category,
                });
            } else {                
                existingItem.quantity = existingItem.quantity + 1;
                existingItem.totalPrice = existingItem.totalPrice + newItem.price;
            }

            // LOCAL STORAGE 
            localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(state.items));
            state.localStorageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));
        },
    },
});
```

And here I'm trying to access those setted cartItems to the localstorage:-

```
//<CartItems />  

//Here state.productItem is from configureStore reducer object:-
// const store = configureStore({
   // reducer: {
     //   productItem: productItemsSlice.reducer,
   // }
// })


const productItems = useSelector((state) => state.productItem.localStorageItems);
const items = productItems.map((el) => {
        return (
            <CartItems
                key={el.id}
                item={{
                    id: el.id,
                    name: el.name,
                    image: el.image,
                    price: el.price,
                    category: el.category,
                    totalPrice: el.totalPrice,
                    quantity: el.quantity,
                }}
            />
        );
    });
```

Please suggest me how can I achieve this, also if I remove items from cart.

Comment: I suggest using the `redux-persist` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `localStorageItems` from `initialState` and add `totalQuantity` key for number of quantity to calculate how many items are added. Now we have to set localStorage for all these 3 initialState with different token key.

Outside of slice function we parse Items:-

```
    const items =
        localStorage.getItem("cartList") !== null
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartList"))
            : [];
    const totalAmount =
        localStorage.getItem("cartTotal") !== null
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartTotal"))
            : 0;
    const totalQuantity =
        localStorage.getItem("cartQuantity") !== null
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartQuantity"))
            : 0;
    
   // adding this function to prevent repear code 
    const setCartListFunc = (items, totalAmount, totalQuantity) => {
        localStorage.setItem("cartList", JSON.stringify(items));
        localStorage.setItem("cartTotal", JSON.stringify(totalAmount));
        localStorage.setItem("cartQuantity", JSON.stringify(totalQuantity));
    };
```

This would be the `initialState`:-

```
   initialState: {
        items: items,
        totalQuantity: totalQuantity,
        totalAmount: totalAmount,
    },
```

Now `addProduct` reducer should be like this to store the data to localStorage:-

```
addProduct(state, action) {
    const newItem = action.payload;

    const existingItem = state.items.find((item) => item.id === newItem.id);

    state.totalQuantity++;

    if (!existingItem) {
        state.items.push({
            id: newItem.id,
            price: newItem.price,
            quantity: 1,
            totalPrice: newItem.price,
            name: newItem.name,
            image: newItem.image,
            category: newItem.category,
        });
    } else {                
        existingItem.quantity = existingItem.quantity + 1;
        existingItem.totalPrice = existingItem.totalPrice + newItem.price;
    }

 // added totalAmount to calculate number of items
    state.totalAmount = state.items.reduce(
        (total, items) => total + Number(items.price) * Number(items.quantity),
        0
    );
    
  // Using function for all initialState
    setCartListFunc(
        state.items.map((item) => item),
        state.totalAmount,
        state.totalQuantity
    );
},
```